# Find the speed of the train given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A train crosses 2 bridges $430$m and $550$m long in $30$ sec and $36$ sec.Find the speed of the train?

options:

a)$36$kmph  b)$72$kmph c)27kmph d)45kmph

My approach:

I did He crossed 430 m bridge first.Therefore,

(430+L)=30 . speed  1eqn

(120 +L)=6 . speed   2eqn

I am confused about how to solve this problem.Can Anyone give me the Hint?

Comment: I think you are missing part of the question.

Comment: @copper.hat I edited the post.It was a typo mistake.Thanu so much :)

Comment: The first sentence gives two speeds for the train.

Comment: @copper.hat Is the second equation right?

Comment: Just read the first sentence. Please. ${430 \over 30} \neq {550 \over 36}$.

Comment: @copper.hat I did not understand.what do you mean?

Comment: If a train crosses a 430 m bridge in 30 seconds, the speed is 51.6 km/hr, if it crosses a 550 m bridge in 36 seconds, the speed is 55 km/hr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29889/discussion-between-jack-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 2):

While it may seem that $\frac{430}{30} \neq \frac{550}{36}$, I think by time it takes the train to cross the bridge, they mean the amount of time from the front of the train reaching the start of the bridge, to the end of the train reaching the end of the bridge.  
Let L be the length of the train, s its speed. Then for any bridge of length B, it will take $t=\frac{B+L}{s}$ seconds for the train to cross the bridge. Rewriting the equation gives us $s=\frac{B+L}{t}$ 
Thus, $s=\frac{430+L}{30}=\frac{550+L}{36}$.  We can solve for L first by cross multiplying: $30 \cdot (550+L)=36 \cdot (430+L)$, I got $L=170$.  Now we easily have $s=\frac{430+170}{30}=\frac{550+170}{36}=20$. 
So the train was moving at $s=20$ m/s (by the way, now the letters like "s" refer to units, not the variables above).  The final step is to convert to km/h: $20 \frac{m}{s} \cdot \frac{3600s}{h} \cdot \frac{km}{1000m}=72$ km/h.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless how long the train might be, it tooks him 6 seconds more for 120 meters more, so v = 20.